# while loop repeating print lines - break?

Tags: python, printing, while-loop

How can I stop this code repeating the print message if the number of characters isn't 11? I want it to repeat the loop until the right number of characters has been typed in but it doesn't do this.

```
phone = input(str("enter the phone number"))

while len(phone) !=11:
    if len(phone)>11:
        print("you entered too many numbers")
    elif len(phone)<11:
        print("you entered too few numbers")
else:
    print ("correct phone number length")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try prompting the user again for input should the length of the phone number not be 11 numbers.

```
while True:
    phone = input(str("enter the phone number"))
    if len(phone) > 11:
        print("you entered too many numbers")
    elif len(phone) < 11:
        print("you entered too few numbers")
    else:
        break

print ("correct phone number length")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    phone = str(input("enter the phone number"))
    if len(phone) == 11:
       break
    if len(phone)>11:
       print("you entered too many numbers")
    elif len(phone)<11:
       print("you entered too few numbers")
```